# How to ignore '\40' expressions and just output the cell-text

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, formatting

So I always use figlet {text} to generate box text for my programs, but this time ~ My C compiler decided to act up. How do I ignore the \40 for this array of text:

```
static char *header =
"  _   _      _                      _      _____          _              \n"
" | \ | | ___| |___      _____  _ __| | __ |_   _| __ ___ (_) __ _ _ __   \n"
" |  \| |/ _ \ __\ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ /   | || '__/ _ \| |/ _` | '_ \  \n"
" | |\  |  __/ |_ \ V  V / (_) | |  |   <    | || | | (_) | | (_| | | | | \n"
" |_| \_|\___|\__| \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\_\   |_||_|  \____/ |\__,_|_| |_| \n"
"                                                       |__/              \n";
```

How would I go about compiling that with no errors?

Comment: "Muahaha! Nobody will think there's a bomb in a box that says '*There's a bomb in this box*'!"

Comment: network trojan junior dev? [Q:Auto-download & execute file on redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883792/auto-download-execute-file-on-redirect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Escape all backslashes:

```
static const char header[] =
"  _   _      _                      _      _____          _              \n"
" | \\ | | ___| |___      _____  _ __| | __ |_   _| __ ___ (_) __ _ _ __   \n"
" |  \\| |/ _ \\ __\\ \\ /\\ / / _ \\| '__| |/ /   | || '__/ _ \\| |/ _` | '_ \\  \n"
" | |\\  |  __/ |_ \\ V  V / (_) | |  |   <    | || | | (_) | | (_| | | | | \n"
" |_| \\_|\\___|\\__| \\_/\\_/ \\___/|_|  |_|\\_\\   |_||_|  \\____/ |\\__,_|_| |_| \n"
"                                                       |__/              \n";
```

This looks weird in the source code, but will print just fine.